# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"SpatVector"’

Tags: r, coordinates, raster, cran, terra

The function "coords" issued from the new package terra seemed not to work on SpatRaster, here a simple example:

```
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
coords(r)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It works in the development version, which is currently being checked for release by CRAN.

Here is a work-around:

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
xy <- coords(as.points(r))
```

For bug reports, it is best to go to https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues